# How to append to multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, arrays

So, I'm using an API that spits out info in JSON, (basically) in this format:

```
{"linkId":"1234asdf","clickData"
["member":{"userId":"asdf1234","email":"email@email.com","firstName":"Joe","lastName":"Schmoe"}]},
["member":{"userId":"fdsa4321","email":"liame@liame.com","firstName":"Moreo","lastName":"Hater"}],
```

--for each link in an email campaign. I want to pull this data via a nested for loop & organize it like so:

```
$linkCount = count($linkArray); //from previous API call

for ($i = 0; $i < $linkCount; $i++) {
    $clickReport[] = //API call here; omitted for brevity
    //parse the JSON here to get $linkid, $url; omitted for brevity
    $memberCount = substr_count($clickReport[$i],'"member":'); //to count number of people listed in JSON response
    for ($j = 0; $j < $memberCount; $j++) {
        //parse the JSON here to get $euid, $fname, $lname, $email; omitted for brevity
        $clickers[] = array (
            $euid[$i] => array (
                'fname' => $fname[$j],
                'lname' => $lname[$j],
                'email' => $email[$j],
                'links' => array (
                        'linkid' => $linkid[$i],
                        'url' => $url[i],
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is if one member clicks more than one link, the nested for loop *overwrites* the previous `'links' => array()`. How can I write this such that `links` is *added* to, rather than *overwritten*?

Comment: You are parsing the JSON? You've heard of `json_encode` and `json_decode`?

Comment: Thx @AbraCadaver -- yeah, I know those functions... but this JSON isn't _actually_ JSON... it's stupid. It's off just enough to tick `json_decode` off, and I found it easier to just parse it myself rather than fix it for `json_decode`. Thanks for throwing that out there, though!!

Comment: @TheresaGoodlett Might be easier then to write a small function which corrects the API response to be valid JSON, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append to it separately.

```
for ($j = 0; $j < $memberCount; $j++) {
    $clickers[] = array(
        $euid[$i] => array(
            'fname' => $fname[$j],
            'lname' => $lname[$j],
            'email' => $email[$j]
        )
    );
    $euid[$i]['links'][] = array (
        'linkid' => $linkid[$i],
        'url' => $url[i],
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @BadHorsie! Was helpful -- albeit just shy of perfect. :) We'll call it answered.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Yeah sorry, I had to guess somewhat.